# Problems with word-break css

Tags: jquery, html, css, cordova

I'm using jquery mobile with phonegap on android.
I have css style

```
.itemClass p{
    width:100%;
    min-height:50px;
    text-transform:capitalize;
    word-break:break-all !important;
    word-wrap:break-word !important;
}
```

I'm creating ul dynamivcally like this

```
...
var out = '<ul data-role="listview">';
$(data["data"]).each(function(index, element){
    out += '<li class="itemClass"><p>' + element.text + '</p></li>';
});
out += "</ul>";
...
```

Styles word-break and word-wrap not applying to items.

Comment: Seems to work for me.  http://jsfiddle.net/R7yTy/2/

Comment: Thank you for answer, but in my case it doesn't work. Can it be some specific problem with using jquery mobile?

Comment: Ah, yes, jQuery mobile has its own, very specific style sheet.  You might look through it and see if something there is overriding your styles.

Answer (score 0):

Your Code is correct.

It is working fine, see this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jt8Vv/) 
But still we can try to add "width" to it's parent **<li>**.

There will be possibility that other CSS may Override your correct code.

You can Try this:

```
.itemClass {
   width:100%;  
}
```